# Does statements about multigraphs imply statements about simple graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Simple question, which is already given in the heading. "If we know a question hold for multigraphs does it mean that this theorem hold for simple graphs as well"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a simple graph a multigraph?  Yes, so any true statement about multigraphs is true of a simple graph.